# Overriding a @Path annotation in a class by method in JAX-RS

Tags: java, jersey

I have a REST API service i maintain in java (over jersey, JAX-RS)

I want to support the following route in my service:

```
/api/v1/users/{userId}/cars
```

however, it concatinates to the class's `@Path` annotation. e.g.

```
/api/v1/cars/api/v1/users/{userId}/cars
```

This is my service class:

```
@Path("api/v1/cars")
public class CarsService {
    @GET
    @Path("/api/v1/users/{userId}/cars")
    public Response getUserCars(@PathParam("userId") Long userId) {
        // ...
    }

    @GET
    public Response getCars() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Is there any way to override it?

Comment: You should be using a different class. It a different root resource, and should be designed as such in your code.

Comment: @peeskillet each API entity has it's own service class (e.g. `UsersService`, `CarsService`). Do you suggest the 2nd approach in the accepted answer? (Placing `getUserCars()` in `UserService`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note the following:

- The [`@Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation in a *class* designates a *root resource*.
- The [`@Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation in a *method* designates a *sub-resource of a root resource*.

When placed on methods, the [`@Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation **does not override** the [`@Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation of the class. JAX-RS/Jersey performs a hierarchical matching using the [`@Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotations.

So, you can try:

```java
@Path("api/v1")
public class CarsService {

    @GET
    @Path("/cars")
    public Response getCars() {
        ...
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/users/{userId}/cars")
    public Response getUserCars(@PathParam("userId") Long userId) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, have you considered using different resource classes?

```java
@Path("api/v1/cars")
public class CarsService {

    @GET
    public Response getCars() {
        ...
    }
}
```

```java
@Path("api/v1/users")
public class UsersService {

    @GET
    @Path("{userId}/cars")
    public Response getUserCars(@PathParam("userId") Long userId) {
        ...
    }
}
```

For more details on resources, have a look at the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html).

Comment: Went on first approach. i wish to place in `UsersService` all `User` entity related stuff same as for `CarsService`. doing the second approach would make it more messy to maintain imho. Thanks Cássio

Comment: @Cassio, I'm following the same approach "different resource classes". But can you tell me, how to upgrade the API version if the same API has to redesign(which is already in use by clients). If do the change in current API it will affect existing client. So we need to create new one. So should I create new Class, if I will create new class then should I copy old other existing API's in this new version also.

Answer (score -1):

You just should change the @Path annotation of the method to:

```
@Path("users/{userId}/cars")
```

In this way, the resulting path of concatenating the class and the method @Path annotations will produce your desired path.

Comment: This result in `/api/v1/cars/users/{userId}/cars/` but I need `/api/v1/users/{userId}/cars/`

Comment: @JossefHarush is right, there is no possible to override class's `Path` you need to create separate controller